# Slide between ViewStub changes

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have a few stubs on my layout and I was wondering whether I could animate them so they slide from one to another.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ViewFlipper for this, as a simple solution. Just have a ViewFlipper as a container for your Views, and assign a sliding animation for it.

For example:

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/Flipper"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
  android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left">
  <Stuff to flip 1/>
  <Stuff to flip 2/>
</ViewFlipper>
```

As for the animations:

Slide out left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromXDelta="0%"
       android:toXDelta="-100%"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Slide in right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
       android:toXDelta="0%"
       android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

You can use ViewFlipper .setDisplayedChild() to do the flipping.

Comment: Many thanks! This was the method I implemented and it works very well. This is the resource I used:
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html